# Reading streaming text over http in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a web service that returns some logs in real time (like a tail -f). I'd like to read that from Angular2 as new lines become available and update a log widget on my page.

How do I accomplish that? More specifically, how do I set up an Observable that's triggered every time a new line arrives over my HTTP connection? I've looked at Oboe, but that seems to be focused on JSON only.